# MDX Query Optimization -- Insert into SQL Table

Tags: mdx, cube

All,

I'm not very familiar with MDX queries, if you are, that make become quickly apparent with this question. This query was modified off a tableau MDX query I copied. I use the query with a linked SSMS server, inserted into a table. This is necessary because of the way I can retrieve the data. The resulting dataset contains many duplicate/null columns/rows and often results in locking conflicts. Can this query be improved? I know it's not ideal way to pull the data but it's all I can do.

```
set @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO db_rpt.dbo.temptable1 from (select * from 
openquery(server,''
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[LEVEL INSTANCE none:Date:qk - lev00] 
AS ''''CASE WHEN IsEmpty([Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) OR [Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue = null 
THEN null 
ELSE CDate([Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) 
END''''
,SOLVE_ORDER = 127

SELECT 
{[Measures].[METRIC1]
,[Measures].[METRIC2]
,[Measures].[METRIC3]
,[Measures].[METRIC4]
,[Measures].[METRIC5]
,[Measures].[METRIC6]
} 

DIMENSION PROPERTIES HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , 
NON EMPTY (Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Dim Employee].[GROUP1].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})
,Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Dim Employee].[Unique Emp Name].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})
,Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Dim Employee].[GROUP2].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})
,Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Dim Employee].[GROUP3].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})
,Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Dim Employee].[GROUP4].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})
,Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Dim Employee].[GROUP5].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}))    ON ROWS 

 FROM [Cube] 
 WHERE (StripCalculatedMembers(Filter(  [Dim Date].[Date].[Date].AllMembers
 ,(([Measures].[LEVEL INSTANCE none:Date:qk - lev00] >= cdate(''''' + @date1 + ''''')) 
 AND ([Measures].[LEVEL INSTANCE none:Date:qk - lev00] <= cdate(''''' + @date2 + ''''')))))
 ,[Dim QA Form Section].[System - Form].[Form].&[Group]&[Form1])'')) t1'
```

Comment: we moved away from openquery due to locking problems and now use the CLR stored procedures provided by this project  https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/

Comment: @whytheq Thanks!, can I use this to select into a SQL table?

Comment: we use it to insert into temporary tables e.g. `INSERT INTO #BLAHBLAH; EXEC ExecuteOLAP @Server, @Database, @MDX;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` can be slower than `IIF` so this could be maybe re-written:

```
CASE WHEN IsEmpty([Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) OR [Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue = null 
THEN null 
ELSE CDate([Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) 
END
```

I think this is equivalent:

```
IIF(
  IsEmpty([Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) 
  OR [Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue = null 
 ,NULL
 ,CDate([Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) 
)
```

It can probably be further simplified to this:

```
IIF(
  IsEmpty([Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember) 
 ,NULL
 ,CDate([Dim Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) 
)
```

---

diagnostic

If you replace this block:

```
WHERE (StripCalculatedMembers(Filter(  [Dim Date].[Date].[Date].AllMembers
 ,(([Measures].[LEVEL INSTANCE none:Date:qk - lev00] >= cdate(''''' + @date1 + ''''')) 
 AND ([Measures].[LEVEL INSTANCE none:Date:qk - lev00] <= cdate(''''' + @date2 + ''''')))))
 ,[Dim QA Form Section].[System - Form].[Form].&[Group]&[Form1])
```

With this:

```
WHERE ([Dim QA Form Section].[System - Form].[Form].&[Group]&[Form1])
```

Does it now run faster? `Filter` is a function that should be used sparingly so I'm just thinking it'd be useful to try the above to see if it is the problem?

Comment: thank you so much for all your help. Current situation... access revoked due to the disruptions caused by the locking conflicts... asked this question a little too late. Perhaps this will help restore my access so I can resume my projects! thanks again.